# Which port range should I use to open a random port?

Tags: port, tcp

I'm writing an application that is broken in two parts, the second should open a random port the first one uses to communicate to it. Which port range should I use to avoid collisions in most platforms (Linux, *BSD, even Windows)?

Comment: In which language you are trying to write a application?

Comment: The one that opens the port in JavaScript running in NodeJS, the triggering app is Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system specific. On Linux, you might want to avoid ports listed in `/etc/services`, see [services(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) and you want to avoid privileged ports (below 1024).

As a guess, you might try in the 10000-30000 range first.

Read also about [tunnel brokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_broker).

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution in such a way that picking a free ports available randomly. 
If you are using python you can go with this:

```
sock.bind(('', 0)). The OS will then pick an available port for you. You can get the port that was chosen using sock.getsockname()[1], and pass it on to the slaves so that they can connect back.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, do not choose port by yourself. If you bind on 0 port, linux kernel will choose free port for you.